# Problem with Dimensional Analysis - Darcy's velocity

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis

Once, by the Darcy law, the flux of a fluid with viscosity $\mu$ in a porous media with permeability $K$ between the points $a,b$ (with distance $L$) is given by

> $$Q=-\dfrac{K}{\mu}(p_b-p_a)\dfrac{A}{L}$$

I think the velocity of Darcy is given by

> $$u=-\dfrac{K}{\mu}(p_b-p_a)\dfrac{1}{L}$$ (it's interesting for me mantain the $L$ at expression)

But my dimensional analysis is not good:

$$\dfrac{\bigg[\frac{m}{s}\bigg]}{\bigg[\frac{N\cdot s}{m^2}\bigg]}\bigg[\frac{N}{m^2}\bigg]\bigg[\dfrac{1}{m}\bigg]=\dfrac{1}{s^2}$$

It might be $m/s$. What is the problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why is permeability $[\frac{m}{s}]$ instead of $[m^2]$? See [Darcy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law#Description).

Comment: Yes, you're right, but now I'm confused... What about this article? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2093700/ *At 35°C, the estimated oxygen permeability coefficients were 51.3, 49.7, and 157.4 cm/s for lens lipid, POPC/Chol, and POPC membranes, respectively*. Many thanks.

Comment: Oh, I was misunderstanding permeability coefficient and intrinsic permeability. Many thanks, Conifold. You can post the answer if you want to.